# Where to change the datetime display format in Dexterity-generated fields?

Tags: plone, zope, dexterity

Dexterity does not use the usual Plone i18n machinery, at least not to display dates in a specific locale. So where to change that if you want, for instance, an ISO-compliant format in an English locale?

Comment: I know the answer, just want to keep for posterity... You can change it in the zope.i18n package, in the XML-files in locales/data.

Comment: Just make it an answer then. :-P

Answer (score 1):

It's in the zope.i18n package, under locales/data. The timecodes are in en.xml for english, equivalent for other languages. Use H for a 24-hour clock.